# SharePoint Online Patch / Release notes

Tags: sharepoint-online, release

maybe a very stupid question but for a long time still i really look for a good place to stay updated with the latest patches / release notes / updates regarding SharePoint Online.

I just can't find a way where microsoft communicates to the customer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are wondering about the CU schedule then you can check it Via Service Adminsitration Portal.

Please read this [FAQ](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/1/4/114B1BD3-DC60-444C-A4CB-9FB1A56AAF64/Aruna/SPO-D%20Cumulative%20Updates%20FAQ.pdf)

here are 2 related questions from that FAQ:

**Does SharePoint Online apply every Public Update?**
SharePoint Online Dedicated customers are organized into 2 patching waves, which means each
customer’s environment will get patched every second published Cumulative Update

**How will I be notified of upcoming Cumulative Update deployments?**

Notification of all CU deployments will be provided at least 5 working days in advance by the Forward
Schedule of Change (FSC) on your Customer Portal, which can be accessed via the Service
Administration portal.

Answer (score 4):

The roadmap is my go to place, http://fasttrack.microsoft.com/roadmap. This will tell you what has recently completed it's full customer rollout, what is currently rolling out, and what is in development. Their official twitter accounts, https://twitter.com/Office365, also give updates when key features start to roll out to first release customers.

Comment: it still goes about the whole office 365 package which makes it a little unclear

Comment: They also do NOT update all Office365 Farms at once (and don't tell you when). I have multiple First Release tenants and all get updated on different days..  Part of them now have the new List Experience, most of the FR Tenants don't have it yet... Its called Cloud technology for a reason... when it rains it pours and no-one can make a valid prediction

Comment: correct, it goes first release then everyone else, in what internal order that goes, who knows

Answer (score 1):

you can find build info at `[tenant]/_vti_pvt/buildversion.cnf`

History I keep track of myself, because I want to know when they allow scripts again:

[image]

Note: There are ofcourse hundreds of Content Farms worldwide